# How do I prevent the textedit box from beeping when enter is pressed?

Tags: c#, text, edit, beep

I have a text edit field in a Windows Form C# application I am developing and after the function occurs, windows dings.  I found some solutions but it applied only to C++ and I couldn't figure how to translate it making the key event to zero since it is a char and illegal cast, even if i do manually cast it to char, it still beeps.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
private void txtPhrase_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                // keyPress seems to initiate the system beep.  Why?
                btnSpeak_Click(sender, e);

            }

 }
```

Comment: Your gravatar + your first tag = me confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to prevent the keystroke from reaching the native control.  Set e.Handled = true

Comment: Thank you Hans!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  It is always true the simplest solutions are often the correct solutions ;-)

Comment: I noticed though if I use the KeysDown method, so I can make use of KeyCode instead to make the code cleaner, I noticed the e.Handled no longer works.

Comment: If you use KeyDown then you have to set e.SuppressKeyPress = true;